# Hide/show admin form field on toggle value using UiComponent in Magento 2

Tags: uicomponent, adminform, magento2.2.3

```
I want Hide/show admin form field on toggle value using UiComponent.

when enable the toggle fields should be visible and on disable the toggle fields should not be visible.

Example:
[When enable the toggle][1]
[When Disable the toggle][2]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
You can use below code for Hide/show admin form field and change field name accordingly.

app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/web/js/form/element/options.js

define([
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function (_, uiRegistry, select, modal) {
    'use strict';

    return select.extend({

        /**
         * On value change handler.
         *
         * @param {String} value
         */
        onUpdate: function (value) {
            console.log('Selected Value: ' + value);

            var field1 = uiRegistry.get('index = test2');
            if (field1.visibleValue == value) {
                field1.show();
            } else {
                field1.hide();
            }

            var field2 = uiRegistry.get('index = test3');
            if (field2.visibleValue == value) {
                field2.show();
            } else {
                field2.hide();
            }

            return this._super();
        },
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do same with text input, like if we open form in edit mode then only field should be visible?

Comment: @RonakChauhan I don't have implement for text input. But you can try with get text input value and check, might that things you can help.

Comment: I have found the solution for text toggle. it can work without js @Kirti Nariya

Comment: @RonakChauhan It is a nice. can you please share that solution as you get. so also it is helpful in future.

Comment: here it is: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301052/how-to-show-hide-uicomponent-form-field-on-based-of-new-edit-mode

Comment: @RonakChauhan Thank you. It is helpful.